# Does jQuery live use setInterval?

Tags: jquery, live

Is the jQuery `live` method using `setInterval` to update the events?

Does this affect performance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [this](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/jquery-live-events) blog as a resource, it appears that jQuery.live() works by attaching the events to the document.  Then, when an event is triggered (such as by a click), the event bubbles up to the document level - at which point it is compared against all the live event handlers.  If it matches a live event handler, it fires the event for it.

Comment: to clarify @Matt’s response, the answer is no. If you’re worried about performance you may be able to see some small improvements using the newer delegate, which lets you apply live-style events within a given parent element.

Answer (score 2):

This blog describes pretty well what's going on behind the scene.

http://www.neeraj.name/blog/articles/882-how-live-method-works-in-jquery-why-it-does-not-work-in-some-cases-when-to-use-livequery

live does not use setinterval but livequery does.

Comment: +1 for pointing to a great overview of live vs. livequery (with an introduction to event bubbling.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it does NOT use SetInterval. I could be wrong.